# Combine fork,fifo and execlp?

Tags: c, unix, exec, fork, fifo

```
int main(){
  mkfifo("view",0666);
  int pid = fork();
  if(pid==0){
    close(1);
    int fd = open("view",O_WRONLY);
    dup(fd);
    execlp("cat", "cat", "users", NULL);
    close(fd);
  }
  else{
    wait(NULL);
    int fd = open("view",O_RDONLY);
    char resp[100];
    read(fd,resp,20);
    printf("%s\n",resp);
    close(fd);
  }
}
```

I have this piece of code but for some reason when I execute it, the procces freezes with no print and with no exit(i have to press CTRL+C). 
Any idea why? I tried the same thing, but using internal pipe and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man [mkfifo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html):

> Once you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any process can
>   open it for reading or writing, in the same way as an ordinary file. 
>   However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can
>   proceed to do any input or output operations on it.  Opening a FIFO
>   for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same
>   FIFO for writing, and vice versa.

The parent process waits in `wait(NULL)` for the child finish, but the child waits for someone to open `"view"` on the other end after the call `open("view",O_WRONLY)`.

---

To have a valid null terminated string you also need to initialize `resp` by zero `char resp[100] = { 0 };` or put zero at the end of read output:

```
ssize_t size = read(fd,resp,20);
resp[size] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfect if I remove wait(NULL) from the parent process. But I don't really know why.